# Can Ant using SSH encrypted private key from Pageant?

Tags: ant, ssh, putty, pageant

`ANT` do have `sshexec` and `scp` task that may read encrypted ssh private key by passing password to the task.  This isn't secure at all.

The `Pageant` from `Putty` stores private key that may used for SSH authentication anytime.  Is there a way to make `ANT` and `Pageant` work together for SSH public key authentication?

Answer (score 2):

ANT uses jsch as it's ssh implementation. This project has recently created a [ssh agent proxy](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch-agent-proxy/), but I don't believe it's integrated into the ANT task yet.